# Currency/Accounting format for inputBox on keyup

Tags: javascript

I need to add formatting to my `inputBox` suited for currency, it should look like this: `£000,000.000`.

This what my script currently looks like:

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', _ => {
    let curVal = elOrderValue.value; 

    let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
    if (isNaN(curValFloat)) {
        elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }

    elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = formatter.format((curValFloat * 0.025) + 4);
});
```

[Here's what the elements look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xJeg.png). [Check out what it looks like on the live site](https://www.carryr.com/pricing). This script currently shows the inputted number value on keyup with an added formula to show a price that's relative to the input value on a separate div block, with currency formatting only on the output. How would I modify this code to add formatting to the inputBox whilst a user is typing? Thanks.

Comment: That is not going to be user friendly FYI. You will have issues with fast typer typing and you swapping out values and the cursor will jump.

Comment: It will be creating problem during typing and it's giving NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an UX expert, but from my experiences I can tell you you shouldn't do it *as long as the cursor is inside the textfield*. Formatting the input while the user is still typing creates a lot of frustration and "weird" behaviour for the user (jumping cursor, suddenly special characters appear, etc.). *Maybe* it's fine to format it back and forth when the input gains and looses focus.

However, to do it regardless what people think about your page and it's usability: Assign the formatted text to the value property of the input:

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('gb-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' });

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', _ => {
    let curVal = elOrderValue.value; 

    let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
    if (isNaN(curValFloat)) {
      elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '';
      return;
    }

    elOrderValue.value = formatter.format((curValFloat * 0.025) + 4); // <-- this line
});
```

Be warned: It will *most certainly* result in bugs/strange behaviour/whatever.

Comment: I think I'll take your word for it. What about validating the number as a currency but placing the £ symbol as a prefix on keyup and then onblur fully validate it with commas and decimals?

Comment: You can add the £ by utilizing CSS and pseudo-elements (use `:before`), so that's out of the way. I cannot decide for you if it's a good idea to format the value of your field on `focus` and `blur` – all I know for sure is, it _is_ a really bad idea to do it while the user is _typing_ :)